# How to fix bash script?

Tags: bash, magento, automation

I am interested in automation of Magento installation. I found one nice [article](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/fully-automated-magento-install-script/) with steps, how to achieve this. I downloaded their script and run it from cli:

```
./mage-install.sh localhost root test "abcABC123" "1.7.0.2"
```

And get such error:

```
./mage-install.sh: 21: ./mage-install.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

I am not familiar with bash, here is a part of code, which is responsible for it:

```
compareVersions ()
{
  typeset    IFS='.'
  typeset -a v1=( $1 )
  typeset -a v2=( $2 )
  typeset    n diff

  for (( n=0; n<4; n+=1 )); do
    diff=$((v1[n]-v2[n]))
    if [ $diff -ne 0 ] ; then
      [ $diff -le 0 ] && echo '-1' || echo '1'
      return
    fi
  done
  echo  '0'
}
```

where line 21 is:

```
  typeset -a v1=( $1 )
```

Can you explain me how to fix it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. The problem is that you're not running it with bash.

Comment: btw, `typeset` is obsolete, don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is with the first line of the script:

`#!/bin/sh`

This specifies what program to use to execute the script when you run it on the command line i.e. `./mage-install.sh`.  The writers probably developed it on a system where `/bin/sh` is symlink'd to their bash installation, but that's not the case on many systems (for instance I have Crunchbang which uses dash instead).

You can either explicitly run it with bash using `bash mage-install.sh blah blah blah` or you can change that first line to point to something that will actually run bash.  You can use `which bash` to see where it lives but it should be in `/bin/bash`

Comment: This is exactly it. Just execute it with bash rather than sh

Answer (score 0):

I should run script like this:

```
bash mage-install.sh localhost root test "abcABC123" "1.7.0.2"
```

Comment: Or simply add `#! /bin/bash` to the first line of your `.sh` file, and execute it with `./script.sh`.